# Error Propagation of a measurement into a 1/log(x) equation

Tags: error-propagation

I have the following equation:
T(°C)=(-4800/((log(x)+log(0.5)-log(1))-5.711)), where x is my variable and it has an uncertainty associated with it. I wanna calculate the error of my temperature considering the error of x. Can someone help me? I'm reading about standard first-order Taylor polynomial method but I don't really know if that is a correct approach nor how to actually calculate it.
Thank you all in advance

Comment: That's a strange formula, given that adding $\log(1)=0$ is superfluous.  Are you sure you transcribed it correctly?

Comment: Where does the equation itself come from? If it's an ordinary regression you may have to take a step back and consider whether your estimates are biased because of the error in $x$.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether statisticians would find this approach sufficiently mathematically rigorous, but a physicist would say that $\sigma_{f}=\bigg| \frac{df}{dx}\bigg| \sigma_{x}$

so you take the derivative of the function, evaluate it at the value of x that you measured, take the absolute value, and multiply by the standard error on x.

Comment: That's great! Thank you very much! Im not sure if I calculated the derivate of my funcion correctly but apparently Im getting the double of the expected error.

Comment: Using the rule for adding logarithms (and assuming your logs are natural base), I write this as $\frac{-4800}{\ln (\frac{x}{2})-5.711}$ which, after differentiating, I get $\frac{400}{x\left(\ln (\frac{x}{2}) -5.711\right)^{2}}$. Is that what you got?

Comment: Not really... I got $\frac{4800}{x\left(\log ({x}) +\log({0.5})-\log({1}) -5.711\right)^{2}}$. My logarithims are at base 10, not natural. I'm sorry, I've should said that earlier. For instance, if my x=8.6 with an uncertainty of 1.8 (2SE), I'm getting a temperature of 800°C (which is correct) but the uncertainty is 39°C and it should be something around 15 or 16. As I'm calculating on Excel, maybe I'm messing up with something...
I really apreciate your help! Thank you very much for everything.

Comment: @Guilherme, please visit https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts to merge your accounts: that will enable you to post comments to your question and even edit it if you need to.